Use Supabase as an OAuth provider
I'm currently evaluating using Supabase as the backend for a new project that involves Alexa skills and I'd like to use account linking. Can we use Supabase itself to mint custom tokens and refresh tokens to support an authentication code protocol as required by Alexa skills?
I can't seem to find anything in the docs other than connecting to existing OAuth providers such as Google etc.
As Alexa is a non-browser environment, I'm not sure the best way to go about this using Supabase as my backend. Previously when using Firebase to do achieve something similar I've been able to use https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
Is this something that's not currently available and I'm barking up the wrong tree?
Thanks

Is there any update on this? I am in the same situation and would be interested in the solution you came up with.
